# Web scraping with Gambas, is it possible?

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, gambas

Using Gambas, is it possible to download a webpage to a string, and then parse that string.
I know I can parse the data in the string once I have the data, I'm struggling with getting the data from the webpage into a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`HttpClient`](http://gambaswiki.org/wiki/comp/gb.net.curl/httpclient) class from the [gb.net.curl](http://gambaswiki.org/wiki/comp/gb.net.curl) component

There you can also find an example how to read the data either synchronous or asynchronous.

To get the data from the web in a string you could write following function (it would be synchronous in this case)

```
Public Function GetTextFromUrl(url As String) As String
    Dim client As New HttpClient As "client"

    client.URL = url
    client.async = False
    client.Get()

    ' an error occured
    If client.Status < 0 Then
        Return ""
    Endif

    ' no data available
    If Not Lof(client) Then
        Return ""
    Endif

    ' Reads the data from the server and returns it as a String
    Return Read #client, Lof(client)

End
```

And you could call the function like this:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Print GetTextFromUrl("http://stackoverflow.com")
End
```